# Given a base and extended class, is casting always needed for base class methods that return objects of the base class type?

Tags: c#

Assume this base class:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass Clone() { 
        /* Returns a full copy of the object. */ 
   }

    /* Constructors here */
}
```

And this derived class:

```
public class ExtendedBaseClass : BaseClass {
    /* ... */

   /* Constructors here */
}
```

If I understand correctly, if an instance of `ExtendBaseClass`, calls `Clone`, an object of type `BaseClass` will be returned. So, this will fail because an explicit cast is missing:

```
BaseClass bc = new();
ExtendedBaseClass ebc = bc.Clone();
```

I have two questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is there a way to prevent an explicit cast from being needed when `Clone()` is called?

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit cast?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede an explicit cast will obviously work.  I'm specifically asking if there's a way to implement this that does *not* require an explicit cast.

Comment: How would that work even with a cast? The object you're cloning is type `BaseClass`, not type `ExtendedBaseClass`. A cast would enable the code to compile but it will throw an `InvalidCastException` at run time.

Comment: It will obviously *not* work, so I guess that's a no, you didn't try it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede So for methods in a base class that return objects of the base class, what should I do?  Do I have to re-implement those methods?

Comment: Your question points to an important misunderstanding in how you think inheritance and/or casting works. I'd review those subjects. Object cloning is messy, and there's no single right way to do it. For example, do you want a deep copy or a shallow copy? [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116554/proper-way-to-implement-icloneable) discusses some of the issues and possible solutions. It's worth asking why you want to clone an object in the first place.

Comment: I see why you come to that conclusion.  I should have asked my question differently (I'm working with someone else's implementation of Clone).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the copy is done - an `ExtendedClass` *is* a `BaseClass`, so if `Clone` looks at the runtime type and creates a new instance of that same type, then the object returned from `Clone` will be an `ExtendedClass`. But, you will need a cast to tell the *compiler* that the object is an `ExtendedClass`, otherwise the compiler will treat it as a `BaseClass` for method binding and other operations.

Or, make `BaseClass` and `Clone` generic:

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T:BaseClass<T> {
    public T Clone() { 
        /* Returns a full copy of the object. */ 
   }

    /* Constructors here */
}

public class ExtendedBaseClass : BaseClass<ExtendedBaseClass> {
    /* ... */

   /* Constructors here */
}

ExtendedBaseClass original;
ExtendedBaseClass copy = original.Clone();
```

Then the compiler will know that `Clone` returns an `ExtendedBaseClass` and you won't need a cast.

Note that this is still not fool-proof, since technically you can define

```
public class ExtendedBaseClass2 : BaseClass<ExtendedBaseClass> {
    /* ... */

   /* Constructors here */
}
```

and `Clone` will return an `ExtendedBaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

To cast to the derived class, the initial object that was created should be of that class.

This will throw an invalid cast exception

```
SomeBase c = new SomeBase();
var d = (SomeDerived)c; // invalid cast exception
```

This will work

```
SomeBase a = new SomeDerived();
var b = (SomeDerived)a;
```

2. 

This is one way, if you are using C# 9.

[Covariant return types c# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns)

> Support covariant return types. Specifically, permit the override of a method to declare a more derived return type than the method it overrides,

[Try in net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n8fbX9)

```
using System;
                   
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       var a = new Derived("XYZ");
       var b = a.Clone();
       Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
       
   }
   
  public abstract class BaseClass
  {
      public abstract BaseClass Clone();
  }
  public class Derived : BaseClass
  {
      public Derived(string name)
      {
          Name = name;
      }
      public string Name {get;}
       public override Derived Clone()
       {
         return new Derived(this.Name);
       }
  }
}
```